# Connect fftw3 library via CMake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, linker-errors, fftw

The project presents a static library with tests. I add the `fftw3` library to it as a submodule, but Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 cannot find this library.

Project Structure:

```
    └───fftw3
    └───googletest
    └───output_64
    └───src
        └───tests
            └───CMakeLists.txt
            └───tests.cpp
        └───CMakeLists.txt
        └───FFT_lib.cpp
        └───FFT_lib.h
    └───.gitignore
    └───.gitmodules
    └───CMakeLists.txt
    └───config_folder_and_run_cmake.bat
```

config_folder_and_run_cmake.bat

```
git submodule init
git submodule update

"c:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" ^
   -H. ^
   -Boutput_64 ^
   -G"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ^
 %*
pause
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.3)

#set the project name
project(FFT)

#set the directories into which libraries and executable files will be collected
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

if(MSVC)
   add_compile_options(
       $<$<CONFIG:>:/MT>
       $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MTd>
       $<$<CONFIG:Release>:/MT>
   )
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

set(SRC_ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(googletest)
add_subdirectory(fftw3)
```

.gitmodules

```
[submodule "googletest"]
    path = googletest
    url = https://github.com/google/googletest
[submodule "fftw3"]
    path = fftw3
    url = https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3
```

src\CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SOURCES
FFT_lib.h
FFT_lib.cpp
)

add_library(FFT_lib ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(FFT_lib PUBLIC ${SRC_ROOT_DIR})

source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} FILES ${SOURCES})

#in solution, this library is located in the FFT_lib folder
set_property(TARGET FFT_lib PROPERTY FOLDER "FFT_lib")

add_subdirectory(tests)
```

src\tests\CMakeLists.txt

```
set(SOURCES
    tests.cpp
)

add_executable(FFT_test ${SOURCES})

# 1. Test library
# 2. gest
# 3. fftw3
target_link_libraries(FFT_test PUBLIC FFT_lib)
target_link_libraries(FFT_test PUBLIC gtest_main)
target_link_libraries(FFT_test PUBLIC fftw3)

set_property(TARGET FFT_test PROPERTY FOLDER "tests/FFT_test")
```

src\tests\tests.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>


#include "FFT_lib.h"
#include <fftw3.h> //cannot open source file  

#include <complex>
#include <vector>


TEST(simple_test, test)
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<complex<double> > data(64, 1.);

    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(data.size(), (fftw_complex*)&data[0], (fftw_complex*)&data[0], FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_execute(plan);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Linker errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: fftw3, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: FFT_test (tests\FFT_test\FFT_test), Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>tests.cpp
2>C:\Work\...\Task-2.2\src\tests\tests.cpp(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fftw3.h': No such file or directory
2>Done building project "FFT_test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
1>   Creating library C:/Work/.../Task-2.2/output_64/fftw3/Debug/fftw3.lib and object C:/Work/.../Task-2.2/output_64/fftw3/Debug/fftw3.exp
1>conf.c.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_solvtab_dft_standard
1>conf.c.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_solvtab_rdft_r2cf
1>conf.c.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_solvtab_rdft_r2cb
1>conf.c.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftw_solvtab_rdft_r2r
1>C:\Work\...\Task-2.2\output_64\bin\Debug\fftw3.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "fftw3.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 8 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

conf.c.obj  is inside the fftw3 library.

Comment: The undefined reference error you see is on `conf.c.obj`, but I don't see this file anywhere in your project. Is there something you are not showing? Can you provide the **full** error message, providing the contextual information about which project is being built when the error occurs, and any surrounding logs? You may be correctly linking `ffwt3` to your test  `FFT_test`, but you may *also* need to link it elsewhere.

Comment: [Archive with the project.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UCnSiAEmHTyuhNCQlMpYfZGEwEcXpR9L/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

In your top-level CMake file, you dive into the `src` directory first, before adding the `googletest` and `fftw3` sub-directories. So, when you reference the `gtest_main` and `fftw3` targets in your `src\tests\CMakeLists.txt` file, they are undefined:

```
target_link_libraries(FFT_test PUBLIC FFT_lib)
# The targets linked here are not yet defined.
target_link_libraries(FFT_test PUBLIC gtest_main)
target_link_libraries(FFT_test PUBLIC fftw3)
```

You should re-order your top-level CMake file such that CMake can find the dependencies *first*, then add the `src` sub-directory:

```
add_subdirectory(googletest)
add_subdirectory(fftw3)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

You will also likely need to add the include directory for the fftw3 headers (path containing `fftw3.h`), with something like this:

```
add_executable(FFT_test ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(FFT_test PRIVATE /path/to/fftw3-headers)
```

Comment: No, it is not. Before connecting fft3w, the gtests worked fine, I also connected other libraries in the same way, for example omp, and everything worked. I changed the order of adding dependencies to the one proposed by you, but this did not help.

Comment: @Patifon_Kakao That is because CMake *caches* some of the results from previous CMake configurations of the same project. You are more likely to see errors when running CMake *from scratch*.

Comment: I deleted the output_64 folder and rebuilt the project in the proposed order. Linker errors disappeared after installing the project with tests  FFT_test as Set as StartUp Project, but it is still impossible to find the header file.

Comment: @Patifon_Kakao The missing header file error wasn't mentioned in your question earlier. When you see this error, it means the `FFT_test` test cannot find the header file, so you need to add the FFTW3 include directories to your test target, as shown in my updated response above.

Comment: I added `target_include_directories(FFT_test PRIVATE ../../fftw3/api)`.   VS found the library, however I got another error `1>------ Build started: Project: FFT_test (tests\FFT_test\FFT_test), Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\Debug\FFT_lib.lib'
1>Done building project "FFT_test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`